# Python - How do you use the tags from pos_tag (NLTK)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nltk, part-of-speech

I have been trying to figure out how to use the 'tagged' results from part of speech tagging. Currently I have this test code:

[image: click to view]

When I run it, it returns with this:

[image: click to view]

This is all fine. But I want to be able to use this result and I don't know how to. How can I check if the 'test' variable contains the 'VBG' tag? Is there a way to check the values of 'test'? I tried doing something like this:

```
if 'VBG' in test: 
   print ('success')
else:
    print('Nope')
    print(test)
```

But this doesn't do anything. How do you find if a word/ string/ attribute is in the result of 'test'? Thanks.

Comment: what is `type(test)`? Also, please do *not* post screen-shots of code. Copy and paste the code into your question *as text*.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `test` returns a list so correct way to check if it contains 'VBG' or any other POS is to index the list. Again, in your case, you'd want to do `if 'VBG' in test[0]`. For a list of words, you can do something like this.

```
import nltk
words = ['doing','cat','blue']
tags = nltk.pos_tag(words)
for idx,word in enumerate(words):
    if 'VBG' in tags[idx]:
        print word + ' is a VBG'
```

PS: Please acquaint yourselves with the etiquette of stack overflow before posting a question.